# Comment utiliser l'expression « si/tant X que j'en oublierais que Y » ?

Tags: expressions, usage

> Je suis **si** choyée **que j'en oublierais que** je suis là pour travailler.

J'ai peine à comprendre *précisément* ce que cette expression veut dire. Est-ce que « si/tant X que j'en oublierais que Y » tout entier est une expression toute faite ?

Pourquoi d'ailleurs faut-il y ajouter le pronom « en » quand la phrase pourrait bien s'en passer ?

---

I’ve just come up with an example sentence with the same construction. Am I using the expression correctly?

> Ma sœur y avait mis **tant** du sien, **que j'en aurais oublié que** c'était la répétition de mon mariage, pas du sien !

Comment: One year later... Isn't "*j'en **aurais oublié***" the right tense to use in the *mariage* example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« **Si X que j'en oublierais que Y** » reprends la forme générale est «… **si X que Y** » (avec X = adjectif).

Sauf tournures régionales, anciennes ou littéraires, « **tant** » ne remplace pas « **si** » dans ces expressions. En revanche, « **tellement** » est un synonyme courant:

« **Je suis tellement choyée que…** »

« **En** » est utilisé dans « **j'en oublierais** » pour renforcer le fait que la proposition secondaire est une conséquence de la proposition principale. On le retrouve dans les expressions similaires « **que j'en perdrais** (mon latin) », « **que j'en mettrais** (ma main au feu)», etc. Une autre justification de ce « **en** » est qu'à l'oral, il réduit beaucoup l'ambiguïté sur le mode utilisé, ici le conditionnel qui indique que l'oubli n'est qu'une hypothèse, et distingue la phrase de son homophone utilisant le futur de l'indicatif:

> Je suis si choyée que j'oublierai que je suis là pour travailler.

Update:

La deuxième expression confirme que « **si** » et « **tant** » ne sont pas interchangeables, la phrase suivant est incorrecte :

> Ma sœur y a mis <s>**si**</s> du sien, que j'en oublierais que c'était la répétition de mon mariage, pas du sien !

mais là aussi, « **tellement** » est utilisable:

> Ma sœur y a mis **tellement** du sien, **que j'en** oublierais que c'était la répétition de mon mariage, pas du sien !

La place de *tant* et *tellement* n'est pas figée alors que **si** suit le verbe et précède l'adjectif :

> **Tant/tellement** ma sœur y a mis du sien…
>
> Ma sœur y a **tant/tellement** mis du sien…
>
> Ma sœur y a mis **tellement** du sien…

One year later, here is a new suggestion with the *conditionnel passé première forme*:

> Ma sœur s'était tellement impliquée (ou investie) que j'en aurais oublié que c'était la répétition de mon mariage, pas du sien !

Comment: Quel est le problème avec « tant » ? Ça se trouve dans la littérature à toutes les époques.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est vrai, ce n'est pas incorrect mais ce que je veux dire et qu'une phrase comme « Il fait tant froid que je me suis couvert » n'est plus vraiment idiomatique.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Is it wrong to use the past conditional instead and say: "Ma sœur y a mis tant du sien, que **j'aurais pu en oublier** que c'était la répétition de mon propre mariage, pas du sien !"

Comment: The past conditional would be fine but "*Ma sœur y a **tant mis** du sien que j'aurais pu en oublier…*" would be "more" correct. According to the [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tant), *Avec un verbe à un temps comp., tant s'insère entre l'auxil. et le part. passé*

Comment: Pourquoi "que j'en oublierai" ne serait-il pas correct ?  Je ne vous suis pas pour la justification liée à l'homophonie, qui d'ailleurs n'est pas généralisée dans toute la francophonie (Dans certaines régions, le "ai" se prononce "é" contrairement au "ais" qui se prononce presque toujours "è") .

Comment: @radouxju « que j'en oublierai » n'est pas incorrect mais introduit un contresens dans l'expression citée où l'oubli n'est qu'une hypothèse peu vraisemblable et plutôt humoristique alors qu'avec « que j'en oublierai », on introduit une certitude sur la survenue de l'oubli, ce qui est très peu plausible.

Comment: One year later... Isn't "*j'en **aurais oublié***" the right tense to use in the *mariage* example?

Comment: Ah, yes! That's right: "***s'était***" instead of "s'est". Likewise, "*y **avait** mis tant du sien*". Thanks. :) By the way, what do you think about adding "y": "*Ma sœur s'**y** était tellement impliquée (ou investie) que ...*"?

Comment: Yes, *y* as an antecedent for *répétition* would work well here.

Comment: "*Je me **suis** tellement senti "chez moi" dans sa maison, que j'en aurais oublié que j'avais payé mon séjour !*" --- This sentence shares the same construction and yet "me suis senti" seems to make more sense than "m'étais senti". What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the *passé composé* is also possible. Both forms sounds good to me.